# When to use Full Simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have an expression,

```
FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[ {{0, -(t1 + t2*Exp[I*ka])},{-(t1 + t2*Exp[-I*ka]), 0}} ]]
```

I am getting the solutions as,

```
-E^(-I ka) Sqrt[E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])], 
 E^(-I ka) Sqrt[E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])]
```

My question is what then fullsimplify does if it doesn't simplify the above expression. Or what command will simplify it.

Comment: Try `PowerExpand[]`, then meditate on what makes roots so special.

Comment: @Feyre I am still getting the same result. No simplification

Comment: Try `PowerExpand[-E^(-I ka) Sqrt[
   E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])]]`, it yields `-Sqrt[t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka]]`

Comment: @Feyre `PowerExpand[-E^(-I ka) Sqrt[
  E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])], 
 E^(-I ka) Sqrt[E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])]]
                                                 Then the output is same                                                                      
Out[15]= -E^(-I ka) Sqrt[E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])]`

Comment: `PowerExpand[{-E^(-I ka) Sqrt[
    E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])], 
  E^(-I ka) Sqrt[E^(2 I ka) (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 t1 t2 Cos[ka])]}]` is the correct way, you forgot to make it a list.

Comment: @Feyre Thanks a lot. I see, but my question is isn't there no command to write in front of the matrix and then get this result. Instead going for one more step.

Comment: `PowerExpand@
 FullSimplify@
  Eigenvalues[{{0, -(t1 + t2*Exp[I*ka])}, {-(t1 + t2*Exp[-I*ka]), 0}}]`

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. It depends on the time zone of your country but still have a great day.

Comment: @Feyre  Be wary when using `PowerExpand`, which ignores branch cuts.  Compare, for instance, `Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@Sqrt[Exp[2 ka I]], {ka, 2 Pi, -2 Pi}]` and `Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@Exp[ka I], {ka, 2 Pi, -2 Pi}]`.  `FullSimplify` does not cancel the complex exponentials in the question, because doing so is incorrect in general.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Sure, but the question was "what command will simplify it [further ed.]". I suppose a warning in my initial comment would have been appropriate though.